# ggplot2 -- zooming in on geom_smooth automatically (using coord_cartesian)

Tags: r, ggplot2

`geom_smooth` is great, in large part because it averages out a lot of variation. However, because of this, it's difficult to see how it varies over the x-axis when it is zoomed out. I am producing about 1000 graphs where I need to have `ggplot2` zoom in via `coord_cartesian`. However, each graph would have different zoom limits. Is there a way I can ask `ggplot2` to zoom in to fit the smooth? I am interested in solutions for both zooming in on just the `geom_smooth` line and the `geom_smooth` line plus SE shaded area.

For example, I would be interested in knowing how I could turn this:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=qsec,x=wt)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

into something like this:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=qsec,x=wt)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(15,20))
```

without explicitly specifying the limits.

Comment: In current version (0.89), it is impossible. In the next version, drawing is fitted for the calculated range, so if you will do `ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=qsec,x=wt)) + geom_smooth()`, then automatically fitted.

Comment: Thanks, @kohske! If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it (might not matter to you but it could make it easier for viewers). Does this currently work in the development version if I feel like giving that a go?

Comment: Looking forward to the new version!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fitting your smoothing models manually gives you much more flexibility for attaining this and other types of customization. For most projects, I start off using the in-line interface, but then usually end up having to switch to manual calculation when I need other tweaks.

See also §9.1.1 in Hadley's book.

```
require(ggplot2)

# Fit smooth manually
fit  = loess(qsec ~ wt, data=mtcars)
newx = data.frame(wt=with(mtcars, seq(min(wt), max(wt), len=100)))
pred = predict(fit, newdata=newx, se=T)
pred = cbind(wt=newx, qsec=pred$fit, se=pred$se.fit)

# Calculate limits based on extent of smooth geom
ylims = with(pred, c(floor(min(qsec-se)), ceiling(max(qsec+se))))

# Plot
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(y=qsec, x=wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(ymax=qsec+se, ymin=qsec-se), data=pred, stat='identity') +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = ylims)
```

[image]

However, this still doesn't work for facets because you can only specify, for example, `scales='free'`, and not the actual limits directly.

Comment: cool, thanks a lot! I might have to try joining the facets together myself then. I will be interested to see how this is improved in the next version.