# geom_smooth (method = "lm", se = False) - I run this and it changes my Y values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lm, geom

I'm having issues when I run geom_smooth. When I run my script without it my y limits are correct, however when I add geom_smooth my y values are incorrect. When I try to set a limit an error pops up telling me I'm loosing 41 rows of data.

#R script without geom_smooth:

#Plotting Chlorophyll by depth with linear regression line

```
depth.vs.chloro<- ggplot(data = Spring, mapping = aes(x=Chlorophyll.RFU, y=Depth.Fixed))+
geom_point()+
scale_y_reverse()+
labs(x="Chlorophyll (RFU)", y="Depth (m)")
ggsave("depth.vs.chloro.png", width=7, height=5)
depth.vs.chloro
```

#R script with geom_smooth:

```
depth.vs.chloro<- ggplot(data = Spring, mapping = aes(x=Chlorophyll.RFU, y=Depth.Fixed))+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se =FALSE)+
scale_y_reverse()+
labs(x="Chlorophyll (RFU)", y="Depth (m)")
ggsave("depth.vs.chloro.png", width=7, height=5)
depth.vs.chloro
```

When I run the last script my Y max value goes from 7, which is correct, to 10 which is not a value in my Depth.Fixed column of my data.

I have tried setting the ylim (0, 7) but this tells me I'm loosing 41 rows of data

Comment: Instead of using `ylim(0, 7)` try `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 7), expand = FALSE)`

Comment: The 41 data points you're losing might be exactly those values where the linear model is predicting values outside of (0,7), which are the ones you *want* to discard?  It would be easier to answer this question with a [mcve] ...

Comment: Related: [geom_smooth() - and scaling the y axis, losing data from smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235844/geom-smooth-and-scaling-the-y-axis-losing-data-from-smoothing) and [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)